# Create Measure - Calculate the Average of values if filters are selected else use the value of "CH"

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I tried to create a measure which should calculate the average number of the selected regions (via Chiclet Slicer).

[image]

If there is no filter set it should take the value of the whole country (CH - which is also part of this table).

In terms of logic, it should read something like this: If FilterIsActive take the average of median_R_mean of the selected regions else select the median_R_mean of "CH".

I have tried this :

```
RE = 
IF(
    ISFILTERED(Region[Bezeichnung]), 
    AVERAGE(COVID19Re_geoRegion_Last_value[median_R_mean]), 
    FILTER(
        COVID19Re_geoRegion_Last_value, 
        "CH"
    )
)
```

Unfortunately this approach does not work.
Can anyone help me on what possible approach I can follow here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correct, you are looking for a measure as below-

```
RE = 
IF(
    ISFILTERED(Region[Bezeichnung]), 
    AVERAGE(COVID19Re_geoRegion_Last_value[median_R_mean]), 
    AVERAGEX(
        FILTER(
            ALL(COVID19Re_geoRegion_Last_value), 
            COVID19Re_geoRegion_Last_value[geoRegion] = "CH"
        ),
        COVID19Re_geoRegion_Last_value[median_R_mean]
    )    
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Most of it works the way it needs to. But the else statement should not calculate the average because there is also the value of FL and CH in the Re_geoREgion_Last_Value table. Therefore I only need to read the value of CH in the table. With FILTER only it does not work. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: If there only on row for CH, this should work as well as some aggregation must need to apply like MIN, MAX, SUM.

Comment: Hi @Angie, nice to see it helped and worked :)